# How to define a directive in gulp-angular-generator using typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using the Yeoman generator [gulp-angular-generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) to create an Angular 1.3 project using Typescript. The seed project shows how to create a controller but not a directive. Here is my failed attempt so far:

**src/app/index.ts**

```js
/// <reference path="../../.tmp/typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="components/workspace/workspace.controller.ts" />
/// <reference path="components/dashboard/dashboard.directive.ts" />

module app {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'restangular', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('WorkspaceCtrl', WorkspaceCtrl)

    .config(function ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'app/components/workspace/workspace.template.html',
          controller: 'WorkspaceCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'workspace'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
}
```

**src/app/components/workspace/workspace.controller.ts**

```js
module app {
  'use strict';

  export class WorkspaceCtrl {
    //some code..
  }
}
```

**src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.directive.ts**

```js
module app {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('dashboard', () => {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'dashboard',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'app/components/dashboard/dashboard.template.html',
        controller: DashboardCtrl
      };
    });

  class DashboardCtrl {
    //some code..
  }
}
```

When I try to run this code I got the following error on the browser console (Chrome):

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either 
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure 
that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Inspecting the browser source files, I realized that the directive file is being loaded before the index where the module definition is present.

I know I could define the entire directive inside `index.ts` the same way the controller is defined (as suggested by the gulp-generator), but that is not a good idea because the Directive Definition Objects (DDO) are usually large and once your app begins to grow it will become harder to maintain.

**Is there a way to define a directive in a different file and instruct the generator to load the files in the proper order?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
module app {
  'use strict';

  export function dashboard(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controllerAs: 'dashboard',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'app/components/dashboard/dashboard.template.html',
      controller: DashboardCtrl
    };
  }
}
```

Read more about how to write directives in typescript here: http://blog.aaronholmes.net/writing-angularjs-directives-as-typescript-classes/

Comment: Thank you, the link to the article was very useful.